# Why a hole is not formed when 5th electron of pentavalent impurity moves to conduction band in n type semiconductor?

Tags: semiconductors, physics

In intrinsic semiconductor, when an electron moves from valence band to conduction band, hole is formed in place of that electron. Why does that not happen in case of n type semiconductor when 5th electron of pentavalent impurity moves to conduction band?

Comment: in short: a hole is in the crystal lattice. The 5th electron of the donor doesn't belongs to the lattice (weakly bounded), thus, doesn't creates a hole when it moves.

Answer (score 1):

When you dope a semiconductor the dopants contribute a mobile charge to the semiconductor of one type and this leaves behind an immobile charge of the opposite charge, this is the ionized dopant atom. If you heat a semiconductor, or expose it to photons of a high enough energy you can generate electron-hole pairs. Since this charge is not created from the ionization of a dopant atom, there is no fixed charge.